# Unable to get each element from variable "coin" to dictionary as key

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do I get dictionary from variable coin which I have define in my code. There are 32 elements in variable coin but I'm getting only one key and value which is `TUSD` in last line.

[image]

```
import requests
import json

r=requests.get('https://koinex.in/api/ticker') 
koinexData=r.json()
koinexprice = koinexData['stats']['inr']

for coin in koinexprice:
  print(coin)
  coindata={}
  coindata["koinex"]={
    coin:{
      "SellingPrice":koinexprice[coin]["highest_bid"],
      "buyingPrice":koinexprice[coin]["lowest_ask"]
      }
    }
#   data.append(coindata)
# print(data)``
# s = json.dumps(coindata)
print(s)
```

Comment: Please include your code as text, so it can be found by search engines and copy-pasted. Your problem seems to be that you're overwriting coindata in every loop iteration btw

Comment: The comments at the end of your code suggest that you were previously building a list of dictionaries to hold your data. Is that not what you wanted to do? What is the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep overwriting your `coindata` dictionary inside the loop, which is why only the last value remains. The second issue with your code is that you keep overriding the `coindata['koinex']` dictionary inside the loop. This should be a list not a dictionary because you'll keep adding values to it.

If you move the initialization code outside the loop, you will not have this problem:

```
coindata = {}
coindata['koinex'] = [] # this should be a list, not a dictionary

for coin in koinexprice:
  print(coin)
  # Create a temporary dictionary d to hold the data you want
  # to add to coindata
  d = {coin: {'SellingPrice': koinexprice[coin]['highest_bid'],
              'buyingPrice': koinexprice[coin]['lowest_ask']}
      }

  coindata["koinex"].append(d) # add the new dictionary to the list

print(coindata)
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need that list. You could do `coindata = {'koinex': {}}`, then later `coindata['koinex'][coin] = {'SellingPrice': ..., 'BuyingPrice': ...}`

Comment: I believe the intention is to create a list of coins, not a dict-of-dicts.

Comment: You might be right, it's not clear exactly what output format the questioner expects.